# bitset to dynamic bitset

Tags: c++, boost, bitset

I have a function where i use bitset.Now i need to convert it to a dynamic bitset..
but i don't know how.
Can somebody help me ?

```
set<string> generateCandidates(set<string> ck,unsigned int k){
 set<string> nk ;
 for (set<string>::const_iterator p = ck.begin( );p != ck.end( ); ++p){
     for (set<string>::const_iterator q = ck.begin( );q != ck.end( ); ++q){
         bitset<4> bs1(*p);
         bitset<4> bs2(*q);
         bs1|= bs2 ;
         if(bs1.count() == k){
             nk.insert(bs1.to_string<char,char_traits<char>,allocator<char> >());
         }
     }
 }
 return nk;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference isn't [that big](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html):

```
boost::dynamic_bitset<> bs1(*p);
boost::dynamic_bitset<> bs2(*q);
bs1 |= bs2;
if(bs1.count() == k){
    std::string str;
    boost::to_string(bs1, str);
    nk.insert(str);
}
```

Comment: … and use `dynamic_bitset` instead of `string`. (`dynamic_bitset` implements `operator<`)

Comment: Agreed, using `dynamic_bitset` and converting to `std::string` only when neccessary would be better.